# How to execute *.sql mysql file in my c# application

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I have a mysql script in a file that I need to be able to execute from my c# application.  Here is a sample of what the script contains:

```
USE osae;

-- Set DB version 
CALL osae_sp_object_property_set('SYSTEM', 'DB Version', '0.3.5', '', '');
CALL osae_sp_object_property_set('SYSTEM', 'Debug', 'FALSE', '', '');
CALL osae_sp_object_type_property_add ('Prune Logs','Boolean','TRUE','SYSTEM',0);
CALL osae_sp_object_property_set ('SYSTEM','Prune Logs','TRUE','','');

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS osae_sp_object_event_script_update$$
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE osae_sp_object_event_script_update(IN pobject varchar(200), IN pevent varchar(200), IN ptext text)
BEGIN
DECLARE vObjectCount INT;
DECLARE vObjectID INT;
DECLARE vObjectTypeID INT;
DECLARE vEventCount INT;
DECLARE vEventID INT;
    SELECT COUNT(object_id) INTO vObjectCount FROM osae_object WHERE UPPER(object_name)=UPPER(pobject);
    IF vObjectCount > 0 THEN
              SELECT object_id,object_type_id INTO vObjectID,vObjectTypeID FROM osae_object WHERE UPPER(object_name)=UPPER(pobject);
        SELECT COUNT(event_id) INTO vEventCount FROM osae_object_type_event WHERE object_type_id=vObjectTypeID AND (UPPER(event_name)=UPPER(pevent) OR UPPER(event_label)=UPPER(pevent));
        IF vEventCount = 1 THEN     
            SELECT event_id INTO vEventID FROM osae_object_type_event WHERE object_type_id=vObjectTypeID AND (UPPER(event_name)=UPPER(pevent) OR UPPER(event_label)=UPPER(pevent));
            UPDATE osae_object_event_script SET event_script=ptext WHERE object_id=vObjectID AND event_id=vEventID;
         -- CALL osae_sp_debug_log_add(CONCAT('Updated ',vObjectID,' - ',vEventID,ptext),'');  
        END IF;
    END IF; 
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see it has a mixture of lines that call stored procedures and some drop and create statements to update other stored procedures.

I have tried two different methods to execute the script and both have failed:

```
MySqlScript script = new MySqlScript(connection, File.ReadAllText("script.sql"));
script.Execute();
```

This throws the exception: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
MySqlCommand upgCommand = new MySqlCommand();
upgCommand.Connection = connection;
upgCommand.CommandText = File.ReadAllText("script.sql");
upgCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This throws an exception that there is an error in my sql syntax.

When I run the entire script manually in dbForge Studio it executes perfectly.  How can I get this script to execute correctly from my C# app

Comment: Will this script ever be changed? If so, it's probably best to have your program execute `mysql` at the command line with the script as the parameter. Otherwise, consume each step in the script into your program; that way the chain is less brittle, i.e. you'll be relying entirely on your own process and not some script that may or may not be there and may or may not work.

Comment: unfortunately I can't use the mysql exe to execute the script because the mysql server may be on a different machine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript.html). You should specify a delimiter for MySqlScript (since you have stored procedure in there). And your query should look like:

```
-- Set DB version 
CALL osae_sp_object_property_set('SYSTEM', 'DB Version', '0.3.5', '', '')$$
CALL osae_sp_object_property_set('SYSTEM', 'Debug', 'FALSE', '', '')$$
CALL osae_sp_object_type_property_add ('Prune Logs','Boolean','TRUE','SYSTEM',0)$$
CALL osae_sp_object_property_set ('SYSTEM','Prune Logs','TRUE','','')$$



DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS osae_sp_object_event_script_update$$
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE osae_sp_object_event_script_update(IN pobject varchar(200), IN pevent varchar(200), IN ptext text)
BEGIN
DECLARE vObjectCount INT;
DECLARE vObjectID INT;
DECLARE vObjectTypeID INT;
DECLARE vEventCount INT;
DECLARE vEventID INT;
    SELECT COUNT(object_id) INTO vObjectCount FROM osae_object WHERE UPPER(object_name)=UPPER(pobject);
    IF vObjectCount > 0 THEN
              SELECT object_id,object_type_id INTO vObjectID,vObjectTypeID FROM osae_object WHERE UPPER(object_name)=UPPER(pobject);
        SELECT COUNT(event_id) INTO vEventCount FROM osae_object_type_event WHERE object_type_id=vObjectTypeID AND (UPPER(event_name)=UPPER(pevent) OR UPPER(event_label)=UPPER(pevent));
        IF vEventCount = 1 THEN     
            SELECT event_id INTO vEventID FROM osae_object_type_event WHERE object_type_id=vObjectTypeID AND (UPPER(event_name)=UPPER(pevent) OR UPPER(event_label)=UPPER(pevent));
            UPDATE osae_object_event_script SET event_script=ptext WHERE object_id=vObjectID AND event_id=vEventID;
         -- CALL osae_sp_debug_log_add(CONCAT('Updated ',vObjectID,' - ',vEventID,ptext),'');  
        END IF;
    END IF; 
END
$$
```

And then your code:

```
MySqlScript script = new MySqlScript(connection, File.ReadAllText("script.sql"));
script.Delimiter = "$$";
script.Execute();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still throws the exception: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Can you try without specifying the DELIMITER $$ and USE (your already have database name in connection string). Take a look at my modified answer. (I've also used wrong delimiter it my code example (##), it is fixed now ($$)

Comment: And also, check example code here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript.html#connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript-delimiter You can try with modifying your code to include just procedure definition. It might happen that your stored procedures calls (at the beginning of the script) are causing problems.

Comment: figured it out.  It looks like that DELIMITER ; at the end was causing the problem.  I see you took it out of our last edit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could run a separate Process to execute the script. For example:

```
Process.Start("mysql < script.sql");
```

You are probably going to need to play around with it a little depending on your environment to include paths to the mysql executable or the sql script.

Comment: Problem with this is the mySql server may not be on the same machine as the c# app

Comment: MySQL client can connect over the network, just like the app (which is a client) just copy over mysql.exe and any needed dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

How if you put your sql script in a stored procedure? If you still want use this way attach the sql file to application as file to the application resources (files .resx) and execute it like that:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmdMySQL = newMySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
cmdMySQL.CommandText = (System.String)globalResource.your_file_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what native MySql syntax is, but when we perform similar functionality for Sql Server, we have to break the sql file into chunks based on the literal values (`GO`) that are only used by the query executor (Sql Server Management Console).

I suspect there may be similar information embedded in your request above, such as the DEFINE statement.

Knowing exactly what MySql complained about would help refine the solution.

Comment: That was my thought as well. GO or it's equivalent isn't SQL and the sql parser chokes on it. Ripping them out or using them to split a long script is teh way we go as well.

Answer (score 0):

Worked For Me:

```
connectOb.conn.Open();
MySqlScript script = new MySqlScript(connectOb.conn, 
"SET @num := 0; 
UPDATE serving_table SET Id = @num := (@num + 1);
ALTER TABLE serving_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");
script.Execute();
connectOb.conn.Close();
```