# How to import to localhost database from a .sql file in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, localhost

I want to import tables from a .sql file into a local database using MySql. I manipulate this database with MySql in C# than I have to export it back into a new .sql file.

Is there a way to do it with MySql and C#?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c-sharp

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855224/how-to-execute-sql-mysql-file-in-my-c-sharp-application