# Executing SQL Script in C# That Contains SOURCE Call

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, syntax

So I'm trying to execute the following `SQL` Code from a `C#` app

```
SOURCE Install/Create_Initial_Index
SOURCE Install/Create_Table_Pk
```

Using the following `C#` code

```
public static void installScripts(MySqlConnection conn, String installScriptPath)
{
    MySqlScript script = new MySqlScript(conn, File.ReadAllText(installScriptPath));
    script.Execute();
}
```

However it is raising a syntax error for the SOURCE keyword

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SOURCE Install/Create_Initial_Index.sql  #
>   20170109 NOT REQUIRED ==>>> SOURCE Inst' at line 1

The SOURCE keyword seems to not work when calling a `.sql` script from `MySQL` workbench, but does work when calling it from the `mysql`> command line. However, it seems that the `C#` code I'm using is the equivalent to calling it from `MySQL` workbench. Does anyone know how I can go about changing my C# code in order to equate the call to that of a `mysql`> command line call. I think this would fix the issue.

Edit 1: I tried doing it by running a shell script from `C#` but it doesn't work because there's a password required to connect

Edit 2: This question is completely different than what someone identified as a "duplicate". Please read the question fully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute \*.sql mysql file in my c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855224/how-to-execute-sql-mysql-file-in-my-c-sharp-application)

Comment: No, it's not...

Comment: You cannot use the SOURCE command in the scripts that are run through the MySqlScript object. It only runs sql commands but the source command is a mysql client command. It is interpreted by the mysql client before sending it to the mysql server. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: @mewkie you misunderstood my point. You're trying to execute "SOURCE somesql.sql" in c# as if it were an SQL statement the server supports, **it isn't**. SOURCE is a command understood by mysql command line client as "load this script and execute the contents". Hence what you're actually trying/wanting to do is "load the contents of <some sql file> into c# and execute it" -> I linked that other question because it solves the problem you're actually trying to solve (have-a-sql-script-in-a-file-and-execute-it-in-c#), not the problem with your broken solution. (The name for this is "XY problem")

Answer (score 0):

I think to change your c# code to work the same way as the mysql> command line client you will need to

- parse the file you read in
- identify the source statements
- load and execute each file in the source statement

Comment: i.e. he should read the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855224/how-to-execute-sql-mysql-file-in-my-c-sharp-application and implement them so that the files with the SQL in (Create_Initial_Index, Create_Table_pk) are read by the c# app (like the mysql command line would), formed into a bunch of sql by the c# (like the command line would) and sent to the server for execution :)